# How to handle deeplink by URI in Navigation graph Android?

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

How to open a deeplink using a CTA Uri in navigation components without losing backstack?

Motivation:

```
private fun openDeepLink(cta: String) { // cta= schema://host
  navigationController?.run{
    val deeplink = this
            .createDeepLink()
            .setDestination(cta)
            .build()

    handleDeepLink(deeplink)
   }
}
```

or

```
 navigationController?.createDeepLink()
            ?.setUriDestination(cta)
            ?.createTaskStackBuilder()
            ?.startActivities()
```

Using

`navigationController?.handleDeepLink(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))`

just works with Up button (toolbar) and not with the system back button. I still can't understand why toolbar and native back are not aligned when I use:

`toolbar.setupWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.activity_base_container))`

and documentation says:

> - @param toolbar The Toolbar that should be kept in sync with changes
>     to the NavController.

With this I understand that toolbar will assume any changes of navController (changes on startDestination, open deeplinks etc)

Comment: find any solutiun  man?